# Using sub parametr in string with VBScript

Tags: string, vbscript, putty, string-concatenation

I have a webpage that pulls a dynamic list of servers, and I want to be able to launch putty/winSCP with the select Linux boxes. I can't seem to pass parameters effectively.

```
    <a href="#" onclick="putty('10.201.38.14');">link</a>
    <script language="vbscript"> 
    Sub putty(hostIP) 
        Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
        oShell.run """C:\Program Files (x86)\putty\putty.exe"" -ssh hostIP" 
        Set oShell = Nothing 
    End sub 
    </script>
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing constant string "hostIP", instead of the `hostIP` parameter value.

Do this instead:

```
oShell.run """C:\Program Files (x86)\putty\putty.exe"" -ssh " & hostIP
```

In VB, the `&` is string concatenation operator and the `hostIP` is reference to the parameter (as opposite to `"hostIP"`, what is a string literal).